# How can I plot Cost function Vs Iterations in Matlab?

Tags: regression

```
function [theta, J_val] = gradesc(X,y,theta,alpha,iter)
  m = length(y);
  for i = 1:iter 

    t1 = theta(1) - alpha*sum(((X*theta) - y).*X(:,1))/m;
    t2 = theta(2) - alpha*sum(((X*theta) - y).*X(:,2))/m;
    theta(1) = t1;
    theta(2) = t2;
    J_val(iter,1) = costfxn(X,y,theta);

  endfor

endfunction
```

The value of J_val(iter,1) is all zeros except for the last one J_val(iter). 
Also, J_val is a vector of iter by 1 dimension.

Comment: Also, I''m very new to Matlab and ML, so please go easy on me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following after endfor:

```
plot(1:iter,J_val)
```

and

> "[...] value of J_val(iter,1) is all zeros except for the last one
>   J_val(iter)"

this is due to the fact that you told the loop to put the new result into the last position, with every iteration (by writing `J_val(iter,1)`). To get each iteration result you have to use `J_val(i,1)`. Next problem that will come up: after correcting this you will get an array J_val that shows the  same value at every position, as you did not specify which input to change with every iteration. How to correct? I think that's something to study for yourself now!

Comment: thanks, it worked :)